# ProgressDialog not dismissed in AsyncTask

Tags: java, android

i have an issue with an AsyncTask. I have an Activity with three CheckBox that if checked launch the async task when the user press the button. My async is this

```
    private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

String valore

            public MyTask(String valore) {
                this.valore = valore;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
                progressDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.message));
                progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
                progressDialog.show();
            }

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                // Exec some operations

                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);
                if(risultato != null) {
                    textView.append(risultato);
                }
                if(errori != null) {
                    textView.append(errori);
                }
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }

        }
```

And the button

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(checkBox.isChecked()) {
                    new MyTask("string").execute();
                }
                if(checkBox2.isChecked()) {
                    new MyTask("string2").execute();
                }
                if(checkBox3.isChecked()) {
                    new MyTask("string3").execute();
                }
            }           
        });
```

The problem is that if two or three checkbox are checked the ProgressDialog is not dismissed and remain on the screen. Why? How can i dismiss it also when two or more checkbox are checked?

Answer (score 1):

```
 try {
                            if ((pDialog != null) && pDialog.isShowing()) {
                                pDialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        } catch (final IllegalArgumentException e) {
                            // Handle or log or ignore
                        } catch (final Exception e) {
                            // Handle or log or ignore
                        } finally {

                            pDialog = null;
                        }
```

> Try dismissing the dialog like this It might solve your problem

There are problem in this code

```
 public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(checkBox.isChecked()) {
                    new MyTask("string").execute();
                }
                if(checkBox2.isChecked()) {
                    new MyTask("string2").execute();
                }
                if(checkBox3.isChecked()) {
                    new MyTask("string3").execute();
                }
            }
```

> this is besically a logical error if we dry run this code it will
>   execute as many time as number of checked checkbox increases .
>   Suppose you do the checkbox1 to checked it will execute the async 1 time 
>   while when you click checkbox2 it will execute checkbox1 async as well as checkbox2 async 
>   and it be so on so change the condition on the button onclicklistner

Answer (score 0):

Hi Since you are creating a new progressDialog every time therefore it is not getting dismissed. Create only one and keep variable at common place . For example

```
@Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                if(progressDialog!=null){
                progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
                progressDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.message));
                progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
                progressDialog.show();
               }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

What are you doing in "doInBackground" method please write that code as well.
And what is "risultato" and "errori" refer to.